# Handling Nulls from database table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I am displaying a database table on a datagridview (Winform) and I have noticed that all the null values of the table have converted on the datagridview to something that resembles blank spaces.
If I check the value of the cell is Null the statement turns false

`dgv.Rows(r).Cells("Fld").Value Is Nothing = True`

If I query the length of the string within the cell I get an error (so these may not be blank spaces).

Ideally I would like to avoid the conversion (have on the datagridview all the nulls from the database table). Is there a way I can stop the conversion?

If this is not possible, how can I identify what those cells now hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in your cells are [System.DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx).
You can test for them using the [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

For example:

```
If IsDBNull(dgv.Rows(r).Cells("Fld").Value) Then
   ' Do Something
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

null and nothing are two differenet things...

The keyword Nothing is used to specify or assign that a var of reference type is not pointing anything, no object is instantiated for this var.

while DBNull.Value is an object used to point out that a type of a field of the db is of null value.

hereyou need to use dbnull...